# sqlite consolidation query

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a simple Table of data (nickname, score) for a simple android game.
Initially I didn't put an unique ID for each nickname and now I have multiple entry from the same nickname.

What I want to do now, is consolidate the data by deleting the "extra" entry from the same nickname and maintain their respective high score.

I was trying to make a query to do that but unsuccessfully.

What do you suggest to achieve the result I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following (I don't have an SQLite installation at the moment to test the precise syntax for the correlated subquery):

```
 DELETE FROM Scores WHERE EXISTS 
    (SELECT * FROM Scores S2 
     WHERE S2.nickname = nickname AND S2.score > score)
```

or (this is correct, thanks to testing by danishgoel in the comments, below)

```
 DELETE FROM Scores WHERE EXISTS 
    (SELECT * FROM Scores S2 
     WHERE S2.nickname = Scores.nickname AND S2.score > Scores.score)
```

Should be perfectly performant for a one-time use over a few thousand nicknames.

This will leave you with duplicates if you have two identical scores for a given nickname, is that possible?

Comment: "Is that possible?" For a game? I'm guessing: Yup!!

Comment: this does not work, the table alias is not supported in Delete Statement as per [DELETE Language Spec](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_delete.html) at sqlite.org. This query errors out at `Scores S1`, as table alias S1 is illegal. I have tried it in SQLite Browser and it gives an error at S1.

Comment: Sorry, don't have SQLite or any tools on the computer I'm using at the moment.  I'm editing to provide an equivalent command without the alias which *should* be valid according to the spec but I'll ask you to test it if you'd be so kind.

Comment: I've tested and your second query, one with Scores.nickname, works just fine. The first does not give an error but no records are deleted.

Comment: Thanks danishgoel for testing it, I'm working on something else right now so couldn't test it, but it looked right, good info on the delete alias thing.

Answer (score 1):

How about creating a new table and adding the entries using this query.

```
INSERT INTO newscorestable(nickname, score) 
SELECT nickname, max(score) 
FROM oldscorestable GROUP BY nickname
```

And deleting the old table

This query set should do it (assuming original table name to be scores).

```
CREATE TABLE scores2 AS 
       SELECT nickname, max(score) as score FROM scores GROUP BY nickname;

DELETE FROM scores;

INSERT INTO scores SELECT nickname, score FROM scores2;

DROP TABLE scores2;

/* to free unused space */
VACUUM;
```

Comment: That could be an option, but I would have then to clear the source table and copy the data back from the "result" table because the table name is hard coded in the game.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to do this:

```
create table temptable (nickname varchar(50), score int);

insert into temptable (nickname, score)
select nickname, max(score)
from yourtable
group by nickname;

delete from yourtable;

insert into yourtable (nickname, score)
select nickname, max(score)
from temptable;
```

**However**, if I were you, I wouldn't delete the scores. You can keep track of every score and then just query what you want.

Want the top 10 high scores? Here:

```
select nickname, score
from yourtable
order by score desc
limit 10
```

Want each user's high scores? Here:

```
select nickname, max(score)
from yourtable
group by nickname;
```

Overall suggestion: ***track everything, query accordingly***.